# compare items of 2 comboboxes

Tags: combobox, javafx, javafx-8

I want to compare the items of 2 comboboxes.
Lets say combobox1 has the items ("a", "b", "c", "d") and combobox2 has the items ("b", "c").
I want to check the items and remove them from combobox1 if there is equality.
So after comparison combobox1 should have the items ("a", "d") and combobox2 should still have ("b", "c").

How can I reach this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
combobox1.getItems().removeAll(combobox2.getItems());
```

Comment: @Zydar happy you if your requirement is really so simple :-) just in case it gets more complex, like f.i. the content of combo2 dynamic, you might consider a FilteredList or one of the list bindings on the first.